# Android exception - External allocation too large for this process

Tags: android, eclipse

I have following code:

```
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;


mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

mPath = new Path();
mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mRealPaint);
}
```

When i run it, it runs fine for few pages. Then after few pictures are done it force closes giving following exception:

```
E/GraphicsJNI(493): VM won't let us allocate 921600 bytes
D/AndroidRuntime(493): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(493): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(493): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

I read many posts on this topic. Updated Large heap to true, but it is still not working. Can someone please help me tell what am i doing wrong here?

More errors:

```
W/webcore(541): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
D/webviewglue(541): nativeDestroy view: 0x40a7b8
I/Ads(541): onReceiveAd()
D/dalvikvm(541): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1943 objects / 219448 bytes in 227ms
D/dalvikvm(541): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 707 objects / 100576 bytes in 159ms
E/ActivityThread(541): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
```

Comment: try it on device and add flag largeHeap=true in your mainefest file

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - I did it still force closes.

Comment: I do not think your issue is related to the snippet you provided

Comment: hay just try to reduce the size of bitmap

Comment: @blackbelt - I added some more errors at bottom do you think it is because of those?

Comment: try to following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: @NoviceMe still don't think error is because of your code

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - I updated this code: mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); Changed 480, 800 to 320, 480. Is that what you meant by reducing size of bitmap?

Comment: yes Change 480, 800 to 320, 480

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - What basically it does? Can i reduce it more? It does not show much changes in pictures though.

Comment: Yes you can reduce it because it is pixel exactly it reduce the size of image

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - Link you provided above has a comment to never use Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888). So should i change that too? What should that be replaced with?

Comment: what do you mean by "When i run it, it runs fine for few pages. Then after few pictures are done... "?? Are you sure you are not leaking references or maybe you should recycle them?

Comment: yes change it and try it

Comment: @marcin_j - This is connecting dot app. So once on page 1 all dots are connected it moves to page 2 and so on. I am new to android development still trying to understand where i am going wrong. All bitmap code is posted above. So do i need to recycle it at the end?

Comment: yes at the end of it you can call bitmap.recycle();

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - What will be scrBitmap in this?? Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, width, height, false)

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - By recycle() at the end you mean after canvas.drawBitmap ?

Comment: Yes you can call it even if you want you can call it in start for eg:-bitmap.recycle();
bitmap=null; than use bitmap

Comment: @YogeshTatwal - Last question Yogesh, can you please put in the answer how i can use:  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, width, height, false) so that i can mark it as answer? Also can you please tell me what will be srcBitmap in this case? As i dont have any above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following  code :-

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth,
        int dstHeight, boolean filter) {
    Matrix m;
    synchronized (Bitmap.class) {
        // small pool of just 1 matrix
        m = sScaleMatrix;
        sScaleMatrix = null;
    }

    if (m == null) {
        m = new Matrix();
    }

    final int width = src.getWidth();
    final int height = src.getHeight();
    final float sx = dstWidth  / (float)width;
    final float sy = dstHeight / (float)height;
    m.setScale(sx, sy);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, width, height, m, filter);

    synchronized (Bitmap.class) {
        // do we need to check for null? why not just assign everytime?
        if (sScaleMatrix == null) {
            sScaleMatrix = m;
        }
    }

    return b;
}
```

src will be your bitmap

Comment: I still did not get it. What is Bitman src?? In my code i just have createBitmap. I do not have any src, so what should i pass in?

Comment: InputStream is = getAssets().open(lol.get(zpositions));   
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  Bitmap mBitmap    = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,width,hight, false);

Comment: have you got the solution ??